# Time complexity for this simple loop

Tags: algorithm-analysis, time-complexity, runtime-analysis, polynomial-time

This is the code:

```
j=2
while j<(n*n)
     j=j*j
```

---

At first my approach was to treat this like this loop

```
i=1
while (i<n)
    i=i*2
```

Which generates on $i$ various powers of $2$  ($i=2^0, 2^1, 2^2....2^k$).

At a certain $k$ iteration, $i$ is equal to or exceeds $n$. 
So $2^k=n$ is the time when the `while` stops.

We find $k=log_2(n)$ which is the number of times the entire `while` loop has been executed, so $T(n)=\theta(log_2n)$.

---

So my idea for the first algorithm was this:
`j=j*j` generates on $j$ different powers of himself, so you can describe it as $j^2$. The problem is that I can't shove in a $k$ iterations in the counting.

The solution for this is actually $log(log(n))$.

Why is this? Can I improve my logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating `i=2*i` generates the powers of two, as you mentioned.

$$
  2=2^1
  \quad
  2*2^1=2^2
  \quad
  2*2^2 = 2^3
  \quad
  2*3^2 = 2^4
  \quad \ldots
$$

Iterating `j=j*j` instead does something more aggressive:

$$
2 = 2^1
\quad
2^1*2^1=2^2
\quad
2^2*2^2=2^4
\quad
2^4*2^4=2^8
\quad\ldots
$$

Note how the exponents grow. In the `i` sequence they are $1,2,3,4,\ldots$.
But in the `j` sequence they are $1,2,4,8,\ldots$. That is, the exponents themselves grow exponentially!

So, the $k$-th element in the first sequence is $2^k$ while in the second it is $2^{2^k}$. That's why the first loop has complexity $O(\log_2 n)$ and the second one $O(\log_2 (log_2 n))$.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track.  For the simpler code, you correctly wrote down the sequence of values that are produced: $2^0,2^1,2^2,\dots$.  In particular, the $t$th output is $2^t$.  Then you were able to find where the loop stops by setting $2^t=n$ and solving for $t$.  That's a great approach.

Try doing the same thing for your actual example.  Hint: the first two outputs are $j$ and $j^2$.  What's next?  Can you generalize What is the $t$th output?  Can you write an equation that represents where the loop stops and solve for $t$?